# Windows Server 2019 Domain Controller: the operating system partition grows until it is full

Tags: filesystems, windows-server-2019

I have a *Windows Server 2019 (Standard Edition)* operating system whose partition runs out of space in a few days (C: has 100GB total) crashing the operating system. It works as a *Domain Controller* (DC) in a small organization. You only have WinRAR, antivirus program and Acronis True Image Services installed; updates for the Operating System are not downloaded.
I have checked temporary files and they are practically empty; the antivirus program hardly generates files, the Acronis logs are minimal. System event logging is well limited. The *pagefile* it´s limited to a 500MB max. The *hibernation* is *off* of course.

**Note:** I migrated this DC several years ago from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008, and last year to Windows Server 2019. I don't think the domain controller objects are enough for the database to grow to fill 100GB.
It only remains for me to extend the C: partition and increase its free space by taking from another partition (a single installed hard drive).

What can be happening?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the files that are the AD database (C:\Windows\NTDS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really, really hope these haven't been in-place upgrades. That is, you installed a new server, joined it to the domain, DC-promoed it, transferred the FSMOs, then unpromoted the legacy DC before removing it from the domain. If you *did* do an in-place upgrade, you probably have a huge Windows.old folder in C: drive.

Assuming it was a clean build, 2019 has a lot of telemetry and monitoring tools turned on by default.

1. Disable telemetry:

- Diagnostic data - Off.
- Tailored experiences – Off.
- Feedback frequency – Never.

2. Stop and disable **UALSvc** (User Access Logging Service) and clear out files and folders in \Windows\System32\Logfiles\SUM\
3. Run `Get-WindowsErrorReporting` to see if WER is enabled. If it is, run `Disable-WindowsErrorReporting` to disable it.
4. Clean up Winsxs. From an elevated command prompt, run `cleanmgr.exe /verylowdisk`. Or run CleanMgr interactively and select the option to scan and clean Windows system files (including updates). If Winsxs doesn't seem to be changing in size even after disk cleanup (and reboot), run `SFC /scannow` to ensure no system files are corrupt. 8 GB or so Winsxs folder size seems to be typical for an averagely-maintained server.
5. Check the Software Distribution folder. If it's many GB, run the following in an elevated command prompt to stop Windows Update services and BITS and clear it out.

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
for /d %G in ("C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\*") do rd /s /q "%~G"
net start wuauserv
```

4. Uninstall any Windows features you aren't using on the server. Running Acronis on a DC seems unfortunate to me (running it on a separate server/workstation seems best). Once you've uninstalled Windows features, let it run a while and ensure no issues. If none, consider running `Remove-Windowsfeature [featurename] -Remove` on the features you already uninstalled. This will completely remove the binaries (and make patching faster). Note that you will need a Window Server 2019 install disk or ISO if you decide you need any of those features back in future.
5. If this still doesn't free up enough space, download Treesize Free and run it to discover what's consuming C drive. By default, it will sort by the largest folder sizes. Winsxs and System32 are likely to be the largest (much of System32 is actually symlinks to files in Winsxs). For anything else on C: that seems to be consuming many GB, if necessary, google the folder to see what it is and the safe method to delete the files (if it's something obvious like IIS log files, then delete what you don't need). Run Treesize multiple times over a few days to see what might be growing.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yeah, it wasn't an upgrade. I Will check every aspect that you propose me.

Comment: I should point out that I made a mistake, the security event log was causing the insufficient space, it was not configured properly.

Comment: Glad it was a simple answer in the end!

Comment: Right, it was something simple that I missed, I didn't notice. In any case, your answer increases my knowledge. Thank you.